# in java i am trying to use & with a filter to get each byte of an integer it works for the last 3 bytes but the first throws a number format exception

Tags: java, filter, byte, bit, parseint

hi thanks in advance for your help,
i am trying to write a program that will allow you to reorder the bytes in a integer i plan on separating the bytes with a filter like so

```
int number = 3;
    int filter = Integer.parseInt("11111111000000000000000000000000",2);
    return number & filter;
```

i wrote a switch statement to select between the four different filters

1. first byte filter = "11111111000000000000000000000000"
2. second byte filter = "00000000111111110000000000000000"
3. third byte filter = "00000000000000001111111100000000"
4. forth byte filter = "00000000000000000000000011111111"

the second to forth filters work but the first one throws a number format exception is this something to do with the sign of the integer?

after seperating the bytes like this i want to use left and right shift to move the bytes and use the OR bitwise operator to combine them back in to a 32 bit integer but in a different order
thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Integer.parseInt` does not expect you to directly pass the bytes you want to set into it, instead it simply interprets the passed String as a binary number so that

> 11111111000000000000000000000000

in binary is

> 4278190080

in decimal system. Which itself is bigger than the maximum value an Integer can hold.

If you want to define your int variables with a binary pattern, then you can quite easily do that which standard java syntax:

```
// using hex syntax
int firstByteFilter = 0xFF000000;
int secondByteFilter = 0x00FF0000;
```

and so on.
There is no need to involve the parseInt method.